# Django Text Formatting, Markup? Markdown?

Tags: python, django

I am very interested in using Django for creating a small travel blog for myself.  There are a few reasons why I am more interested in using Django instead of something like Wordpress.  One is that I am interested in having a grip on all the details and in the end creating something that doesn't look like a wordpress blog, the second, is that I want several blogs, one for each place I visit, which isn't natively handled by wordpress.

The problem is that when I'm abroad, I want to be able to type a blog that will automatically create paragraph tags for me at the very least and handle a lot of the small html formatting tyoe things that Wordpress does for you.  What is the common workflow for something like this? I don't want something crazy like TinyMCE, but something above having to type every little html tag.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options out there.  Markdown(http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/) is an obvious one.

But you could also look at https://github.com/syrusakbary/pyjade which provides a simplified structure.  I think that Markdown is a bit more forgiving and easier to work with.

Comment: I actually went with regular https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown, not sure the major differences, but am extremely happy with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any richtext editor than I would personally recommend using reStructuredText with Sphinx: http://sphinx-doc.org/

It is a very complete markup language with extensions to support pretty much anything. The entire Python documentation is written in reStructuredText and these days the html output generated by Sphinx.

Example of a project which does something similar: http://tinkerer.me/

Comment: I am familiar with Sphinx, but would like to stay within the Django framework because of its relation to databases etc.  If Sphinx has capability, its not documented very well.

Comment: @dvreed77: I'll admit it's less than trivial to find, but documented nontheless: http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/web/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches, first one is [turning autoescape off](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) in parts of your templates.

And the second one is using [`django.contrib.markup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/markup/) which provides filters for [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29), [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [reStructured Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText). For which you need to install [PyTextile](http://loopcore.com/python-textile/), [Python-markdown](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) or [doc-utils](http://docutils.sf.net/) respectively.

**EDIT**

Just noticed that `django.contrib.markup` is deprecated in Django 1.5, "mainly because of security issues with 3d party libraries", however, if the input is trusted (that is, you trust all your users), you can copy `django.contrib.markup` from Django 1.4.